# Python - Can only concatenate list not float to list

Tags: python, concatenation

I understand that I can only concatenate things of similar types, but I'm really confused as to why the following are of different types.

```
n = 100
table = [[0]*n for x in range(n)]
array1 = [[0] for i in range(n)]
mini = array1[1] + table[1][1]
```

I am trying to make mini store the integer that is the result of array1[1] and a table[1][1]'s value. But I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

There must be something simple I'm missing. When I print just table[1][1] I get 0, so why is table[1][1] not treated as just 0 (I.e. 0 + 0)?

Comment: `print array1` - it's an array of arrays.  is that what you expected?  the problem is not with `table1`, but with `array1`

Comment: @andrewcooke a `list` of `list`s. `array` means something quite different in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `table[1]` is indeed `[0]*1` which is `[0]`, and `table[1][1]` is indeed `0`.
- but **`array[1]` is `[0]`**, which is a list
- thus your attempt to do `array1[1] + table[1][1]` is actually `[0] + 0`

To debug such things in the future, print each part of the expression the interpreter is complaining about:

```
print(array1[1])
print(table[1][1])
```

Answer (score 2):

> so why is `table[1][1]` not treated as just `0`

It is - but `0` cannot be added to `array1[1]` with `+`. It's exactly as the error message says. `+` is used to add two `list`s together:

```
[1, 2, 3] + 4 # WRONG: can't concatenate a non-list with a list
[1, 2, 3] + [4] # RIGHT: concatenates the two lists, producing [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If `array1[1]` is intended to be a `float` rather than a `list`, then `array1` should store numbers rather than lists. The code `array1 = [[0] for i in range(n)]` makes each element in `array1` be `[0]`, i.e. a list.

That said, please remember that array indexes *start with 0*.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what `array1` contains:

```
>>> array1[1]
[0]
```

It's not a list filled with zeroes, it's a list filled with a bunch of lists, each of them containing a single zero.

you probably want this line:

```
array1 = [[0] for i in range(n)]
```

to be this:

```
array1 = [0 for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is my first Python program so I knew I'd be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Both `table` and `array1` are lists of lists of integers (0 in this case). But

```
array1[1]
```

is a list of integers while

```
table[1][1]
```

is an integer. You could solve the problem using a slice, like this:

```
mini = array1[1] + table[1][1:2]
```

which results in `mini` being equal to

```
[0, 0]
```

The slice `table[1][1:2]` is itself a list containing a single element (`table[1][1]`), and since concatenating lists is allowed, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `array1` is a list containing lists that each only have a single element, 0, for i in `range(n)`. That is, `array1[1] = [0]`, not `array1[0] = 0`. That's why the types mismatch.

Also, don't forget that Python is 0-based, not 1-based. It doesn't cause an error here, but seems to betray your thinking of [1] as the first slot in the list, when [0] is.

Answer (score 0):

When you print each operand, you will get the following output:

```
>>> array1[1]
[0]
>>> table[1][1]
0
```

So the first is a list, and the second is a single integer. As such it obviously fails.

So you either need to use `array1[1][0]` to add the integer values, or use `table[1]` to concatenate lists.